# Get latest status of an item in the database

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

```
ID|Item-FK |timestamp|status
=============================
1 | 123    | ...     | OK
2 | 123    | ...     | FAILED
...
```

I want to query get all items which *last* status was `FAILED`.

If an item failed yesterday, and is OK today, I don't want to see it.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Phil I use PostgreSQL. I did not tell it, since I thought this can be solved with standard SQL. But it seems not that easy....

Comment: It's not that hard, either. Any way, please *always* declare your RDBMS. If you prefer a standard SQL solution, just say so in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use Partition by to get last record where Status is failed.

```
    ---Test table
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[items](
        [id] [int] NULL,
        [Item-FK] [int] NULL,
        [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
        [status] [varchar](200) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

--dummy data 
INSERT [dbo].[items] ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (1, 123, CAST(0x0000A3E0006DB876 AS DateTime), N'ok')
INSERT [dbo].[items] ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (2, 123, CAST(0x0000A3E1006DB876 AS DateTime), N'FAILED')
INSERT [dbo].[items] ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (3, 124, CAST(0x0000A3E1006DB876 AS DateTime), N'ok')
INSERT [dbo].[items] ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (4, 124, CAST(0x0000A3E1006DB876 AS DateTime), N'ok')
INSERT [dbo].[items] ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (5, 125, CAST(0x0000A3E1006DB876 AS DateTime), N'FAILED')

--- Query to get all items who's last status is 'Failed'
    SELECT  *
    FROM    items
    WHERE   [Item-FK] IN (
            SELECT  [Item-FK]
            FROM    ( SELECT    row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY [Item-FK] ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC ) iid,
                                *
                      FROM      items
                    ) item
            WHERE   iid = 1 AND [status] ='FAILED')
```

**EDIT**: you can use EXISTS instead on IN

```
SELECT  *
FROM    items itm
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT [Item-FK]
                 FROM   ( SELECT    row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY iitm.[Item-FK] ORDER BY iitm.[timestamp] DESC ) iid,
                                    *
                          FROM      items iitm
                        ) item
                 WHERE  item.iid = 1
                        AND item.[status] = 'FAILED'
                        AND itm.[Item-FK] = item.[Item-FK] )
```

Comment: You don't need `IN` or `EXISTS` or 3 levels of nesting. 2 levels is enough. And it should probably be `ORDER BY timestamp`, not `BY id`.

Comment: @ypercube, yes you are right order by should be on timestamp,but to get all items I am using IN\Exists

Comment: @ypercube, I added table and dummy data insert statements with my answer, with 2 level nesting it return only 2 rows instead of 3 rows

Comment: You've also assumed which RDBMS the OP is using. MySQL doesn't support `row_number()`, for example.

Comment: @Phil, Row number generation also possible with MySQL. "SET  @ row_number:=0;
SELECT @ row_number:=@row_number+1 AS rownumber FROM items 
ORDER BY [timestamp] desc;"

Answer (score 2):

#### Postgres specific

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_fk)
          item_fk, status
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY item_fk, timestamp DESC
   ) sub
WHERE  status = 'FAILED';
```

Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

#### Standard SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t1
WHERE  status = 'FAILED'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   tbl t2
   WHERE  t2.item_fk = t1.item_fk
   AND    t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
   );
```

Both assume that `(item_fk, timestamp)` is defined `UNIQUE` - or it's broken by design.

Aside: [Use legal identifiers.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Thank you very much. What is PostgreSQL specific in the first solution?

Comment: @guettli: `DISTINCT ON`. You find detailed explanation in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the SQL windows function to work for me, kept returning two values for [Item-FK] = 123. I'm a newbie to that though.

I was able to get it using a nested select. This code assumes your [timestamp] column is unique.

And sorry for the formatting! I'm new to dba.stackechange and haven't figured out the bes way to paste in T-SQL.

--Test table

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#items') IS NOT NULL

    DROP TABLE #items

CREATE TABLE #items(

    [id] [int] NULL,

    [Item-FK] [int] NULL,

    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,

    [status] [varchar] ( 50 ) NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


-- dummy data 


INSERT #items ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (1, 123, DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT,RAND()*100), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'OK')

INSERT #items ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (2, 123, DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT,RAND()*100), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'FAILED')

INSERT #items ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (3, 124, DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT,RAND()*100), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'OK')

INSERT #items ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (4, 124, DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT,RAND()*100), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'OK')

INSERT #items ([id], [Item-FK], [timestamp], [status]) VALUES (5, 125, DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT,RAND()*100), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'FAILED')

-- wait 1 second for the data to be committed.

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

-- Query to get all items who's last status is 'Failed'

SELECT  items.*

    FROM #items items

    INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Item-FK], [timestamp] = MAX([timestamp]) FROM #items GROUP BY [Item-FK]) AS items_last

        ON items.[Item-FK] = items_last.[Item-FK]

        AND items.timestamp = items_last.timestamp

    WHERE items.[status] ='FAILED'

Comment: Welcome to dba.SE. Please merge your two answers into one and format properly. [Consider the markdown help](http://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help).